# Two links to the same image lightbox

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, lightbox

I need to add 2 different link to the same lightbox gallery (http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/). The problem is that if i set as href the same image url, when I click on one of the links I get the same image repeated two times.
Here is the code I write:

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url().'gallery/'.md5($annuncio['id']).'/'.$first_image; ?>" rel="lightbox[gallery]">first link</a>
<a href="<?php echo base_url().'gallery/'.md5($annuncio['id']).'/'.$first_image; ?>" rel="lightbox[gallery]">second link with same image url</a>
<a href="<?php echo base_url().'gallery/'.md5($annuncio['id']).'/'.$second_image; ?>" rel="lightbox[gallery]">third link to a different image</a>
<a href="<?php echo base_url().'gallery/'.md5($annuncio['id']).'/'.$third_image; ?>" rel="lightbox[gallery]">fourth link to a different image</a>
```